# Incrementing id recipe - takeEvery, but queue worker till worker ahead of has taken id

Tags: redux-saga

Is there a best practice way for incrementing id's in redux-saga?

This is how I am doing it, but if multiple requests dispatched at same time, multiple things are getting the same id:

My data shape of the reducer is this:

```
const INITIAL = {
    lastId: -1,
    entries: []
}
```

And here is my saga:

```
function* requestDownloadWorker(action: RequestAction) {

    // other workers should wait

    const id = (yield select()).downloads.lastId;
    yield put(increment());
    console.log('incremented the lastId incremented, for whoever needs it next');
    // other workers can now continue

    // below logic - should happen in parallel with other workers
}
function* requestDownloadWatcher() {
    yield takeEvery(REQUEST, requestDownloadWorker);
}
sagas.push(requestDownloadWatcher);
```

I think I need to `takeEvery` but queue `worker` until the previous `worker` has declared it has finished taking an `id`, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an actionChannel that buffers all REQUEST actions until you "take" them.

```
import { actionChannel, select, take } from 'redux-saga/effects'
...

function* requestDownloadWorker() {
  const channel = yield actionChannel(REQUEST)
  while (true) {
    const action = yield take(channel)
    const id = (yield select()).downloads.lastId
    yield put(increment())

    yield fork(doOtherParallelStuff)
  }
}
```

It should work.

Comment: Oh wow thank you Felipe! This is super cool. I have a offline system, what if actions are buffered, and the app is shutdown, can i restore that buffer on next start?

Comment: Not sure you can restore that buffer, but maybe you could implement a custom solution using a redux middleware to persist incoming actions and removing from persistence when you get the corresponding success action. When waking up from a crash, for example, the app could then dispatch the remaining actions that are persisted. Maybe you could also do that by creating a saga middleware and listening for effects. Take a look at SagaMonitor.

Comment: Thank you for those ideas Felipe! I will share what I come up with. :)